# Dynamic permission policy to access sqs queue based from name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, aws-policies, aws-iam-policy

I want to create a dynamic permission policy with attributes substitution that allows access to respective customer's queue (indicated as part of the SQS queue name)

For example:
SQS queue name: individual-queue-${insert-attribute-by-customer-name}

I created an IAM role to grant access in sqs access policy with name: generic-sqs-access-role-dynamic-attributes

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sqs:DeleteMessage",
            "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
            "sqs:SendMessage",
            "sqs:GetQueueAttributes"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:accountID:general-queue-abc",
            "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:accountID:individual-queue-${insert-attribute-by-customer-name}"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sqs:ListQueues",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

my sqs access policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountID:root"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:accountID:individual-queue-${insert-attribute-by-customer-name}"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "__sender_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountID:role/generic-sqs-access-role-dynamic-attributes" // the role with permission policy as stated above
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:accountID:individual-queue-${insert-attribute-by-customer-name}"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "__receiver_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountID:role/generic-sqs-access-role-dynamic-attributes"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SQS:ChangeMessageVisibility",
        "SQS:DeleteMessage",
        "SQS:ReceiveMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:accountID:individual-queue-${insert-attribute-by-customer-name}"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I assumed the role and tested with cloud9, the dynamic policy doesn't work. Those that are able to assume the role `generic-sqs-access-role-dynamic-attributes` are able to access all the queues (both general and individual queues with customer names appended to them)

I expected the dynamic attributes in the IAM role policy would be able to restrict based on the queue name which will substitute the customer name

i.e. customer-a can access only arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:accountID:individual-queue-customer-a

customer-b can access only arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:accountID:individual-queue-customer-b

but they can't access each other's queue

I tried with conditions but not much luck.

What has gone wrong here? Is that my IAM policy issue or SQS access policy issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it work this way

2 different IAM policies splitting from the above IAM policy - 1 with resource of general queue only, 1 customer specific queue

In SQS access policy, I added in attribute substitution in the individual queue

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountID:root"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:accountID:individual-queue-${insert-attribute-by-customer-name}"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "__sender_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountID:role/general-access-role"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:accountID:individual-queue-${insert-attribute-by-customer-name}"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "__receiver_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountID:role/general-access-role"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SQS:ChangeMessageVisibility",
        "SQS:DeleteMessage",
        "SQS:ReceiveMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:accountID:individual-queue-${insert-attribute-by-customer-name}"
    }
  ]
}
```